# "He thought his sister was/had been playing with his toys when he wasn't there"

Tags: grammaticality, past-tense, sequence-of-tenses, reported-speech

Which of (1) and (2) is (or are) “correct”, and when and why?

1. Yesterday Rachel **said** that she **was practicing** dancing two days ago.
2. Yesterday Rachel **said** that she **had been practicing** dancing two days ago.

Here if I want to say that he thought his sister was playing with his toys
earlier, then which of these is (or are) “correct”?

3. He **thought** his sister **played** with his toys when he **wasn’t** there.
4. He **thought** his sister **was playing** with his toys when he **wasn’t** there.
5. He **thought** his sister **had been playing** with his toys when he **wasn’t** there.
6. He **had thought** his sister **had played** with his toys when he **hadn’t been** there.

Is the simple past ever ok for this sense?

Does it truly matter whether you use one of these versus the others — will
anybody actually notice which one you say?

What do native speakers normally say here?

Comment: These don't have right-vs-wrong answers. Both are valid. The thing is that those do not mean the same thing. That you are asking this implies a confusion derived from a misunderstand of simplified materials used to teach English language learners rather than native speakers. So I will migrate this question to somewhere you're apt to get answers suited to your learning level. First I need to edit it to fix your errors in orthography (capitalization, punctuation, etc).

Comment: @tchrist thanks for that and could you answer these questions ?

Comment: They’re all basically ok but could mean slightly different things. 3 & 4 make it sound like the toy playing is something that happens every time the brother isn’t there, while 5 & 6 sound like they are talking about a single instance.

Comment: After the simple past, you can use any past tense in the second clause but it changes the meaning. Perhaps you should review those individually: present perfect, present perfect continuous, imperfect.

Comment: @ tchrist "The thing is that those do not mean the same thing." What do you mean? To me sentence nr 1 means " she said: "I was practicing dancing the day before" and sentence nr 2 is the  indirect speech and correct version of that sentence.

Answer (score 1):

(1/2) Neither tense is obviously wrong. I would find it more natural to say

> Yesterday, Rachel said that she had been practising dancing the day before.

(She was speaking yesterday, so 'two days ago' would have been 'yesterday' then!)

(3) means that the sister often played with the toys, (4) that she was playing with them *at the time*. (5) and (6) give the required meaning of 'earlier'. **When he wasn't there** is better because it's simpler.

Comment: But wouldn't  you say "her dancing" here?

Comment: @Lambie - Not necessarily.

Comment: Not sure why you'd want "practising her dancing" any more than "practising her football" or something else.